Save Python dictionary to Json
I'm trying to save a python dictionary to disk as a json file. From this Q/A, the answer should be
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

However, in my application (AWS Lambda) the error I receive is
{
  "errorMessage": "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",

I have verified that data's type is indeed a dictionary. So I'm curious why json.dump(data, f) is treating data as if it were a string, not bytes. Perhaps the python Lambda runtime introduces some unexpected behavior (I do have ephemeral storage enabled)
def upload(data):
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') 
    s3=boto3.resource('s3')
    with open('/tmp/output.json', 'wb') as temp_file:
        json.dump(data, temp_file)    
    
    data_ = open(temp_file,'rb')
    s3.put_object(Body=data_, 
                      Bucket='bucket', #replaced  
                      Key=f'Solution/{date}/data.json')
    os.remove(temp_file)    


Are you absolutely sure the error happens on the json.dump() call?  As shown, the error message does not identify the offending line of code or line number.  How do you know the error is on that specific line of code?

You opened the files in binary mode. Use "r" and "w" like the example instead. Also, it's a good idea to specify the encoding in case the default value is wrong.

Where, exactly, do you see that error?  Python certainly does not deliver error messages in JSON format.  Your first open will, indeed, read as string, because you didn't use 'rb', but that wouldn't produce an error.

Or is that actually the contents of the JSON?

The error is that json.dump tries to write a str and the byte file object complains.
